# Adding a webhook to rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, webhooks

I'm looking to add a webhook to a rails application that will post entries to a database depending on if an email is sent to it.

Has anyone here done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Mandrill and @app.yourdomainnamehere.com

1. http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview
2. http://tardate.blogspot.com/2013/02/easy-mandrill-inbound-email-and-webhook.html
3. If your staging site is behind HTTP auth, you can include the username and password within the staging webhook url for testing purposes.

Any specific questions?